# "Select All" is showing transparent selection in Edttext Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-color

In my Edittext when i "Select All" the text, the selected text is visible and the selection is transparent
[image].

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_rounded_corner">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Ask something...?"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:minHeight="45dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/base"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the style being applied to the activity? This may be the one being used app-wide if there is no specific one. It may be in `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`.

Comment: how  you selecting all text ?

Comment: check the color of your `colorAccent` in `theme.xml`

Comment: I used the theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark"` to my activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define colors in your colors.xml

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#125688</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#104d7a</color>
```

Use this in your AppTheme like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/text_highlight_green</it‌​em>
</style>
```

and use this style in your Activity

Comment: added this in styles.xml  `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/text_highlight_green</item>`

Comment: otherwise primary color is choosen for selecting text

Answer (score 2):

Just use `TextHightLight` Property in `EditText` in XML Mode

```
android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
```

This will solve your issue...